# Subtract previous row to calculate column value in MS SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, date, window-functions, gaps-and-islands

I have below data which needs to be formatted to display only consecutive days without a break.

For example, I want to display the records with dates from `2018-06-18` until `2018-06-21` as these are consecutive days. But then I don't want to show rows with dates of `2018-06-27` or `2018-07-03` as these days don't have a sequence.
The exception is for `Friday-Monday` where there will be obvious gap. For example if the dates are `2018-06-21` (Thursday), `2018-06-22` (Friday) and `2018-06-25` (Monday), than that will be a valid sequence.

Sequence of `2018-6-1`, `2018-6-3`, `2018-6-4` has to be hidden as it is broken (there was no record of `2018-6-2` in the table).

I had written below, but it fails to deliver the output I am looking for. Any help will be greatly appreciated.

```
select date, diff, Percent_gain, day, month, Year
from (
   select date
      ,datediff(day, '2018-1-29',date) - coalesce(lag(datediff(day, '2018-1-29', date)) over (order by date), 0) as diff
      ,Percent_gain, day, month, year
   from tab
) t1
where t1.diff < 2
   and t1.Percent_gain < 0
```

[image]

Output

[image]

Comment: So what *is* the output you are looking for? Also, sample data is far better provided as well formatted `text` or DDL and DML statements. Please don't expect the users here to transcribe your data, as it's unlikely they will.

Comment: Thanks. I have added intended output based off the sample data provided. All the days which were in sequence must be visible.

Comment: 2018-6-1 and 2018-6-3 is not in sequence but why is 2018-6-3, 2018-6-4 not considered as consecutive days.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use window functions and a conditional expression:

```
select *
from (
    select t.*, lag(date) over(order by date) lag_date
    from mytable t
    where percent_gain < 0
) t
where 
    lag_date is null
    or date = dateadd(day, case when datename(dw, date) = 'Monday' then 3 else 1 end, lag_date)
```

The subquery filters on rows whose `percent_gain` is negative, and uses `lag()` to retrive the `date` of the "previous" row. Then, the outer query filters again according to the following criteria:

- either the row is the "first" one (ie there is no previous date)
- or the date of the current row one day after the previous date - excepted if the current date is a Monday, in which case the current date should be 3 days later than the previous date

Note that the query does not actually uses columns `day`, `month` and `year`; those look like derived values, that can easily be computed on the fly when needed. Typically, we use `datename()` to get the day name.

Comment: Aside: `( @@DateFirst + DatePart( weekday, SampleDate ) - 1 ) % 7 + 1` will always return an integer from `1` to `7` with `1` corresponding to Sunday regardless of the setting of `DateFirst` or `Language`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this as an alternative to find sequence.

```
WITH dates(id ,date)
AS
(
 SELECT 1, '2020-03-10'   UNION 
 SELECT 2, '2020-03-15'   UNION
 SELECT 3, '2020-04-17'   UNION
 SELECT 3, '2020-04-20'   UNION
 SELECT 3, '2020-04-21'   UNION
 SELECT 3, '2020-04-22'   UNION
 SELECT 4, '2020-04-25' 
)

Select A.*,CASE WHEN day_name = 'MONDAY'
                THEN CASE WHEN datediff(d,A.prev_date,A.date) = 3
                          THEN 1
                          ELSE 0 END
                ELSE CASE WHEN datediff(d,A.prev_date,A.date) = 1
                          THEN 1
                          ELSE 0 END
                END AS Is_seq

from (Select t.*, DATENAME(dw,date) as day_name,
             lag(date) over (order by date) as prev_date
      from dates t
     ) A
```